# Cassandra - "line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'" with "Mapping.Delete<T>" method

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-driver

When we trying delete using `Cassandra.Mapping.Delete<T>` method the application throws an error on execution:

[image]

This is a 'Entity(POCO)' class on application:

[image]

Table structure in Cassandra database:

[image]

Complete exception description:

> An exception of type 'Cassandra.SyntaxError' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '''
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Cassandra.Requests.PrepareHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Cassandra.Requests.PrepareHandler.d__4.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Cassandra.Session.d__54.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Cassandra.Mapping.Statements.StatementFactory.d__8.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Cassandra.Mapping.Mapper.d__38.MoveNext()
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)

What is wrong?

FYI: these links don't solve this problem:

S.O: ["no viable alternative at input" error when querying cassndra table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484518/no-viable-alternative-at-input-error-when-querying-cassndra-table)

S.O: [Cassandra "no viable alternative at input"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117170/cassandra-no-viable-alternative-at-input)

**[SOLVED]**

Thanks @jorgebg, we forgotten to specify the partition key on "Entity" mapping class.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying the partition key in your mappings? https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.6/features/components/mapper/#configuring-mappings

Comment: You are the man! Sorry for this!